# Generating points near the certain point (landmark) on a network

Tags: r, spatstat

Let's assume we have a network and a fixed point on the network (like a landmark such as a stop sign or traffic light).

I can use `runiflpp(n, a linnet object)` to generate uniformly distributed points on the network but is there a way to only generate points around this landmark but still on the network? Is there a way to specify the distance like 5 or 10 meters around this point?

Comment: Hello!  We need more details about the problem you are trying to solve, and a sample of your data to respond.  Use dput(yourdataframe[1:10] )    to share the first ten rows, for instance, and paste the output into your question.

Comment: Example data is not needed. The question is about the `spatstat` family of R packages (specifically about `spatstat.linnet` which deals with networks). The question asks for a counterpart of the function `runiflpp` to generate random points on a network with non-uniform probability density. The answer is given by @rubak below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help file for `runiflpp()` points to `rlpp()` for non-uniform random
points, and `rlpp()` allows you to use a function or image on the linear
network to specify the intensity of points. So one strategy is to specify a
function or image which is a positive constant close the point of interest
(POI) and zero elsewhere:

```r
library(spatstat.linnet)
L <- simplenet
P <- lpp(c(.5,.5), L) # POI
plot(P, main = "Point of interest (POI)")
```

[image]

```r
Dfun <- distfun(P) # Distance function to POI
plot(Dfun, main = "Distance to POI")
```

[image]

```r
f <- function(x, y, seg, tp){ #' Function which is 1 "close" to POI and else 0
  ifelse(Dfun(x = x, y = y, seg = seg, tp = tp) < 0.3, 1, 0)
}
closefun <- linfun(f, L) # As function on the network
plot(closefun, main = "Indicator of closeness to POI")
plot(P, add = TRUE, cex = 2, pch = 20)
```

[image]

```r
X <- rlpp(n = 10, f = closefun)
plot(X, main = "Random points close to POI")
```

[image]